# Error 3160009: No wast file found

Tags: eosio-code, docker, eosiocpp

---

The hello world contract is not getting compiled in the EOS v1.3 and eosio.cdt. The wasm and abi file is getting created but goes undetected. https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/5349

Answer (score 3):

The problem here was that the path provided was relative, and Rohan was working with a docker container. When passing the path to your contract's directory when using docker, it should be an absolute path, and match the mounted path of your docker container.

```
cleos set contract helocode1234 /contracts/hello helo.wasm helo.abi -p helocode1234@active
```

The docker image is presently not configured properly, as there is a client (cleos) that lives **inside** of the container. Most problems you will encounter of this nature while dealing with paths and a docker-based cleos relates to this particular issue.

Confusion surrounding this part of the stack will be addressed in a future release.

*Old Answer:*

Try this

```
cleos set contract helocode1234 ./helo helo.wasm helo.abi -p helocode1234@active
```

If you call `cleos` without positionals it will return a help menu, or otherwise you can provide `--help` argument.

```
cleos set contract
```

returns

```
Positionals:
  account TEXT                The account to publish a contract for (required)
  contract-dir TEXT           The path containing the .wasm and .abi
  wasm-file TEXT              The file containing the contract WASM relative to contract-dir
  abi-file TEXT               The ABI for the contract relative to contract-dir
```

Comment: The contract dir contract-dir TEXT fixed it for me. I was not using docker. Btw documentation on https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/v1.3.0/reference#cleos-set-contract doesn't have this dir in it